# I can't get AMQP publish and subscribe to run with Node JS v6 and mqlight v2.0 from IBM MQ v9.0.1.0

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq, amqp

I am trying to get the example snippet to publish and subscribe below, I can't get it to run with Node JS 6 and mqlight v2.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqlight?cm_mc_uid=47189062138014548006442&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1490060435

```
// Receive:
var mqlight = require('mqlight');
var recvClient = mqlight.createClient({service: 'amqp://user:user@localhost:5672'});
recvClient.on('started', function() {
recvClient.subscribe('/TEST/#','sub1');
recvClient.on('message', function(data, delivery) {
          console.log(data);
     });
});

// Send:

 var sendClient = mqlight.createClient({service: 'amqp://user:user@localhost:5672'});
 sendClient.on('started', function() {
     sendClient.send('TEST');
});
```

i run the sample code mqlight 2.0 with node js v6

```
$node mqlight_sample.js

      events.js:160
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
  SecurityError: AMQXR0100E: A connection from 172.17.0.1 was not authorized.
      at lookupError (/media/Data/mqlight/node_modules/mqlight/mqlight.js:1034:11)
      at AMQPClient.<anonymous> (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/mqlight/mqlight.js:1925:13)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at AMQPClient.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at Connection.<anonymous> (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/amqp_client.js:388:10)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at Connection._processCloseFrame (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/connection.js:495:10)
      at Connection._receiveAny (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/connection.js:423:12)
      at Connection._receiveData (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/connection.js:357:8)
      at NetTransport.<anonymous> (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/connection.js:515:38)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at NetTransport.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/anonim/Data/mqlight/node_modules/amqp10/lib/transport/net_transport.js:26:49)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

this one error log from MQ Server

```
# tail -100f /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/errors/amqp_0.log

3/31/17 19:14:44.115  AMQXR0041E: A connection was not authorized for channel SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP received from 172.17.0.1. MQRC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
3/31/17 19:14:45.142  AMQXR0041E: A connection was not authorized for channel SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP received from 172.17.0.1. MQRC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

actually authenticate for AMQP is enabled if CONNAUTH and CHCKCLNT required changed to disabled i can connected with Node JS 6

```
START SERVICE(SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE)
SET CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody')
SET CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) USERSRC(CHANNEL) CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
START CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP)
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(SYSTEM.DEF.AMQP) CHLTYPE(AMQP)
```

below the error log from /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/errors/AMQERR01.LOG

```
04/02/17 07:10:16 - Process(587.6) User(mqm) Program(java)
                    Host(770e29171038) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.1.0) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ5534: User ID 'user' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the 'AMQP' program could not be
authenticated. 
Additional information: 'N/A'.
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct user ID and password are provided by the application.
Ensure that the authentication repository is correctly configured. Look at
previous error messages for any additional information.
----- amqzfuca.c : 4486 -------------------------------------------------------
04/02/17 07:10:16 - Process(587.6) User(mqm) Program(java)
                    Host(770e29171038) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.1.0) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ5542: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(REQDADM) configuration.

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'user' and its password were checked because the queue manager
connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication
information (AUTHINFO) object named 'USE.OS' with CHCKCLNT(REQDADM). 

This message accompanies a previous error to clarify the reason for the user ID
and password check.
ACTION:
Refer to the previous error for more information. 

Ensure that a password is specified by the client application and that the
password is correct for the user ID. The authentication configuration of the
queue manager connection determines the user ID repository. For example, the
local operating system user database or an LDAP server. 

If the CHCKCLNT setting is OPTIONAL, the authentication check can be avoided by
not passing a user ID across the channel. For example, by omitting the MQCSP
structure from the client MQCONNX API call. 

To avoid the authentication check, you can amend the authentication
configuration of the queue manager connection, but you should generally not
allow unauthenticated remote access.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/02/17 07:10:17 - Process(587.6) User(mqm) Program(java)
                    Host(770e29171038) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.1.0) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ5534: User ID 'user' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the 'AMQP' program could not be
authenticated. 
Additional information: 'N/A'.
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct user ID and password are provided by the application.
Ensure that the authentication repository is correctly configured. Look at
previous error messages for any additional information.
----- amqzfuca.c : 4486 -------------------------------------------------------
04/02/17 07:10:17 - Process(587.6) User(mqm) Program(java)
                    Host(770e29171038) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.1.0) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ5542: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(REQDADM) configuration.

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'user' and its password were checked because the queue manager
connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication
information (AUTHINFO) object named 'USE.OS' with CHCKCLNT(REQDADM). 

This message accompanies a previous error to clarify the reason for the user ID
and password check.
ACTION:
Refer to the previous error for more information. 

Ensure that a password is specified by the client application and that the
password is correct for the user ID. The authentication configuration of the
queue manager connection determines the user ID repository. For example, the
local operating system user database or an LDAP server. 

If the CHCKCLNT setting is OPTIONAL, the authentication check can be avoided by
not passing a user ID across the channel. For example, by omitting the MQCSP
structure from the client MQCONNX API call. 

To avoid the authentication check, you can amend the authentication
configuration of the queue manager connection, but you should generally not
allow unauthenticated remote access.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This question is not clear, for example what error did you receive when you didn't run this code?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc i was changed question maybe now it's clear.

Comment: I was changed the password to `password` and host `amqp://user:password@localhost:5672` different between user but i still got error

Comment: I used AUTHENMD to used users OS and the script to set AUTHINFO

`DEFINE AUTHINFO('USE.OS') AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH('USE.OS')
DISPLAY AUTHINFO('USE.OS') AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) 
     1 : DISPLAY AUTHINFO('USE.OS') AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)
AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.
   AUTHINFO(USE.OS)                        AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)
   ADOPTCTX(NO)                            DESCR( )
   CHCKCLNT(REQDADM)                       CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)
   FAILDLAY(1)                             AUTHENMD(OS)
   ALTDATE(2017-03-31)                     ALTTIME(18.50.21)`

Comment: Response is blank when i type `echo 'password' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user` after i tried to connect with sample code and the error is same before.

Comment: If i set `CONNAUTH` like this `ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH('')` it's work but the authenticate become disabled right ?

Comment: I was logged in as mqm the response for `echo 'password' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user` still blank.

Comment: The response outpout is `0` after tried to connect.

Comment: The result is `0` same with above.

Comment: Sorry i'm wrong to saw the output is `1` not `0` confirm now correct. when i run command `echo 'badpassword' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?`

Comment: Sorry i was wrong saw the output command `echo 'badpassword' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?` is `1` not `0`.

Comment: Yes with the correct password is `0`.

Comment: Please remove all the comments from this question and my answer, I'll be doing the same.  All comments on this question and my answer are captured either in the question, my answer, or your final answer.  Please be sure to accept your final answer as well by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer under the arrow that points down.  Also if you thought my answer was helpful in troubleshooting this issue please give me a upvote by clicking the up arrow to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASL flow has been changed within the new Node JS client version. The new SASL flow is currently not supported by the IBM AMQP server. The AMQP server thinks that at this moment it should already have enough data for authentication and authorization of the client user. However, because of the change in the new Node JS client, the rest of the required data has not yet been sent when the server tries to authenticate the client. This is why the logs show that only the user 'mqm' has been set and no password supplied to the QMgr. Thus causing an authorization error APAR IT20283

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing the error logs from the queue manager it appears that MQ is not able to authenticate the user being passed to the AMQP channel via the mqlight_sample.js program.

Please try the following two commands and note the output:

```
echo 'goodpassword' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?
echo 'badpassword' | /opt/mqm/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?
```

OP noted the output was 0 and 1 for the above commands.  This means that MQ can properly authenticate the the UserId "user" with a correct password since it returns 0.

Next please create a normal SVRCONN channel on the queue manager and try the following sample program, this would again rule out MQ and CONNAUTH being an issue.

```
echo 'goodpassword' | amqscnxc -x 'localhost(5672)' -c SVRCONN.CHANNEL -u user QM1; echo $?
```

The output if good should look like this:

```
Sample AMQSCNXC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1
using the server connection channel SVRCONN.CHANNEL
on connection name localhost(5672).
Enter password: Connection established to queue manager QM1
Sample AMQSCNXC end
0
```

If output if it fails should look like this:

```
Sample AMQSCNXC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1
using the server connection channel SVRCONN.CHANNEL
on connection name localhost(5672).
Enter password: MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035
243
```

If the above test is also successful then please verify that the mqlight_sample.js has the same user and goodpassword values that worked with the two tests.

If you find that the UserID and password are correct, then it would appear that the amqp program is not passing the password correctly and someone else with more AMQP knowledge would need to help.

---

**Update 2017-04-28**

OP @dhaavhincy has posted a new answer that per IBM the issue was a result of the SASL flow in Node JS v6 being changed and incompatible with IBM MQ AMQP.  IBM has provided that this will be fixed via APAR IT20283 which has not been published to the web.

**Update 2017-06-20**

[APAR IT20283](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT20283) was published to the web around May 22nd.

Comment: Output to verified user id and password is correct
`-bash-4.2$ echo 'password' | /opt/ibm/mqm/901/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?
0
-bash-4.2$ echo 'badpassword' | /opt/ibm/mqm/901/bin/security/amqoamax user ; echo $?
1`

it's used amqp this one sample can't run
`echo 'goodpassword' | amqscnxc -x 'localhost(5672)' -c SVRCONN.CHANNEL -u user QM1; echo $?`

Comment: I created normal channel SVRCONN this is different port with AMQP 

`-bash-4.2$echo 'password' | amqscnxc -x 'localhost(1414)' -c TEST.SVRCONN -u user QM1; echo $?
Sample AMQSCNXC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1                                     
using the server connection channel TEST.SVRCONN
on connection name localhost(1414).
Enter password: Connection established to queue manager QM1                                     
Sample AMQSCNXC end
0`
this one correct user and password

Comment: and this one the badpassword or incorrect password
`-bash-4.2$ echo 'badpassword' | amqscnxc -x 'localhost(1414)' -c TEST.SVRCONN -u user QM1; echo $?
Sample AMQSCNXC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1                                     
using the server connection channel TEST.SVRCONN
on connection name localhost(1414).
Enter password: MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035
243`

Comment: I did supply same user and password above for AMQP but it's not connected
`var mqlight = require('mqlight');
var recvClient = mqlight.createClient({service: 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672'});
recvClient.on('started', function() {
recvClient.subscribe('/TEST/#','sub1');
recvClient.on('message', function(data, delivery) {
          console.log(data);
     });
});`
my reference string set user and password
[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqlight?cm_mc_uid=47189062138014548006442&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1490060435)

Comment: Hi @JoshMc
SASL flow has been changed within the new Node JS client version. The new
SASL flow is currently not supported by the IBM AMQP server.
The AMQP server thinks that at this moment it should already have enough data for authentication and authorization of the client user. However,
because of the change in the new Node JS client, the rest of the required data has not yet been sent when the server tries to authenticate the client.
This is why the logs show that only the user 'mqm' has been set and no password supplied to the QMgr. Thus causing an authorization error

APAR IT20283

Comment: Hi @JoshMc yes that's informed from IBM